# passing an array in "Basic" OpenOffice Programming

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, libreoffice, libreoffice-basic

I've been asked to do something at work, and being that I'm running Ubuntu and not Windows, I have Libre Office (LO Writer is the equivalent of Word). - The task is to automate some contracts, where the document stays 90% the same except for a few variables that change from doc to doc.

First of all - Basic is a nightmare, and generally this whole Macro writing process is also pretty awful.

Now to the "code" - I keep getting some error about `BASIC error: Argument is not optional` 
and all I'm trying to do is pass two arrays to another function:

```
Function test ( ByVal changeFrom() As String ,ByVal changeTo() As String  )
Dim I As Long
Dim Doc As Object
Dim Replace As Object

Doc = ThisComponent

Replace = Doc.createReplaceDescriptor
For I = 0 To 2
  Replace.SearchString = changeFrom(I) //Error is here
  Replace.ReplaceString = changeTo(I)
  Doc.replaceAll(Replace)
Next I
End Function


REM  *****  BASIC  *****
Sub main
Dim changeFrom(3) As String
Dim changeTo(3) As String


changeFrom() = Array("<word2>", "<word3>", "<word1>")
changeTo() = Array("value1", "value2", "value3")
test( changeFrom , changeTo)
End Sub
```

Generally -

does anyone know a better way for me to do this OTHER than "Basic" which is really driving me crazy..
I understand it can be done with Python, but I kind of wish there was an even easier way, problem is the word document has tables and things which need to be defined, so I can't just copy/paste the template in to a java class and modify it..

Thanks!

Comment: Is it possibly because you defined an array of four items, but only gave it three values?[Libre Office Basic Arrays](https://help.libreoffice.org/Basic/Using_Variables#Arrays)

Comment: I don't see what's wrong, but the [Libre Office Basic Guide(download)](http://ask.libreoffice.org/upfiles/13691375437855071.odt) covers this on page 83.

Comment: yeah I've downloaded the guide - thanks - however this doesn't help me with my error..

Comment: Don't you need the `Call` keyword before `test( changeFrom , changeTo)` like in VBA?

Comment: Not according to the guidebook - 
Can anyone recommend a less tedious way/language of doing this? Sounds so simple but I'm not able to make it happen

Answer (score 2):

the Basic function ARRAY() returns a VARIANT that contains an array. So if you use the function ARRAY, you have to dial with Variants:

```
Function test ( ByVal changeFrom As Variant ,ByVal changeTo As Variant  )
Dim I As Long
Dim Doc As Object
Dim Replace As Object

Doc = ThisComponent

Replace = Doc.createReplaceDescriptor
For I = lbound(changefrom) To ubound(changefrom)
  Replace.SearchString = changeFrom(I) 'Error is here
  Replace.ReplaceString = changeTo(I)
  Doc.replaceAll(Replace)
Next I
End Function


REM  *****  BASIC  *****
Sub main
Dim changeFrom As variant
Dim changeTo As variant

changeFrom = Array("<word2>", "<word3>", "<word1>")
changeTo = Array("value1", "value2", "value3")
test( changeFrom , changeTo)
End Sub
```

Or if you don't use the function ARRAY, you can use String() arrays:

```
Function test1 ( ByVal changeFrom() As String ,ByVal changeTo() As String  )
Dim I As Long
Dim Doc As Object
Dim Replace As Object

Doc = ThisComponent

Replace = Doc.createReplaceDescriptor
For I = lbound(changefrom) To ubound(changefrom)
  Replace.SearchString = changeFrom(I)
  Replace.ReplaceString = changeTo(I)
  Doc.replaceAll(Replace)
Next I
End Function


REM  *****  BASIC  *****
Sub main1
Dim changeFrom(2) As String
Dim changeTo(2) As String

changeFrom(0) = "<word2>"
changeFrom(1) = "<word3>"
changeFrom(2) = "<word1>"

changeTo(0) = "value1"
changeTo(1) = "value2"
changeTo(2) = "value3"

test1( changeFrom , changeTo)
End Sub
```

Greetings

Axel

Comment: Axel's solution should function fine if you change the call to use test1 rather than test in main1.

Answer (score 1):

I think that an array is ALWAYS passed as a reference, even if you state that the parameter is by value. I would need to verify that this is still true, but call it 90% certain.

The provided answer properly uses LBound and UBound to use only the limits as set for the passed array. This is likely the largest part of your problem. Now, that said, you can simply the macro and do something like this:

```
Function test1 (Doc, changeFrom, changeTo)
Dim I As Long
Dim Replace As Object

' A paranoid person would verify the parameters. Things like:
' Are the parameters NOT IsEmpty and Not IsNull
' Is the Doc object really a text document
' Are the other parameters really arrays

Replace = Doc.createReplaceDescriptor
For I = lbound(changefrom) To ubound(changefrom)
  Replace.SearchString = changeFrom(I)
  Replace.ReplaceString = changeTo(I)
  Doc.replaceAll(Replace)
Next I
End Function


REM  *****  BASIC  *****
Sub main1
  test1(ThisComponent, Array("<word2>", "<word3>", "<word1>"), Array("value1", "value2", "value3"))
End Sub
```